# How to detect ">" and "<" keypresses in .NET console application

Tags: vb.net, console, keyboard-events

Given the following code...

```
Dim KeyPress As ConsoleKeyInfo
Do
    KeyPress = Console.ReadKey(True)
    If KeyPress.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(">") Then
      debug.WriteLine("Greater Than")
    End If
Loop While KeyPress.Key <> ConsoleKey.X
```

I would expect that pressing the ">" key on my keyboard would produce the debug output.  However, when I  step through my code, the IF statement evaluates to false when ">" is pressed.

What is the correct method to detect the ">" keypress when using Console.ReadKey()?

Comment: Interestingly I would expect that to be flagged up with Option Strict On but it doesn't appear to

Comment: @dwroelands: is your issue fixed now?

Comment: My issue is fixed, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an actual char literal: `If KeyPress.KeyChar = ">"c`

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple change in your code:

```
    Dim keypress As ConsoleKeyInfo
    Do
        keypress = Console.ReadKey()
        If keypress.KeyChar = Chr(62) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Greater Than")
        End If
    Loop While keypress.Key <> ConsoleKey.X
```

Or you can use Like

```
    Dim keypress As ConsoleKeyInfo
    Do
        keypress = Console.ReadKey()
        If keypress.KeyChar = ">"C Then
            Console.WriteLine("Greater Than")
        End If
    Loop While keypress.Key <> ConsoleKey.X
```